# Stripe - Add billing address on invoice

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I've been using Stripe to manage my subscriptions and I'd need to add a billing address on this invoice and I can't figure out how.

Here are the informations stored in the customer

[image: customer]

And on my invoice, I get this without the billing address on it.

[image: invoice]

Is there any way to add it?
I tried specifying the shipping address on it, but it doesn't add itself down there, it's added under "Ship To" and not under "Bill To", obviously

Answer (score 1):

When an invoice is finalized, we take a snapshot of the customer's information at that time and store it on the Invoice. The billing address for an invoice is pulled from `customer.address` and set to `invoice.customer_address` (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-customer_address)). If the invoice has already been finalized, there is no way to update it to add the billing address of the customer.

If the invoice has not been finalized (it's still a draft), you would set the billing address for the invoice by updating the customer itself:

- In the dashboard you'd just edit the customer and update their billing address.
- Through the API you'd make a request to update the customer and set `address` (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-address))

Comment: That mean that we must update the customer each time we want to pay an invoice, if we want to let the customer choose the shipping address he want... So what the paymentIntent shipping address and paymentMethod billing address are used for ?